# JWT Token in Symfony2

Tags: angularjs, symfony, authentication, oauth, jwt

I need read JWT Token in controller Symfony2 and this send to $localStorage on frontend (isn't standard login process).

I use AngularJS 1.4, Symfony2.7 (REST), LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle.

How I can read this token for logged user in controller?

(example JWT Token:  eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXUyJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0NTMyODkzNzAsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoibWFjaWVqLm9zeXRla0BnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOiIxNDUzMjAyOTcwIn0.P8d4dDSkUk26U6voqeDxJ6RtH2sy_d1fBcB_XHx_E8AOfmQuib3E54ERIRhuhl4T7bFTzpmpOZ-K-RcpkkdjfvlsfaM1R9KRkDVHXZ1KpQs4nF1u4SZef6SorAES-d4ZSnouKLS3BRLayXtpTOLGjzaq3RpKVIAIEZtEQNvKTZBUdvCvDd2X-_UmyMAxgFShNvpw2CSLmdFys45KjfcTP9l74hsK7-l5kkkqywa-q4feIPVkLHJ-J41oU2l6jGf_KbHW4pTNFJ_6X7c-awkHRxyphrcXbtK_BlBiwOff7hOsODTZhIBh2StTnmO0jegIlKlVxsnlP652zYzf2NsqhcIz0hblknmeOZV_hit-liEXuNZy4-7Ee_Tn2bLusGOIGVnniuVFSkZIGtvoV8KJWuj7mXefmTln_rPyI04RQy9m1BW3V3h2TmEKgpK4c01p5c2wx6CCtSV0SLCcKMA2p1-fYMkOgQ0J4YrZ4nrMcRHh6P8rsb9NSnTlwmOrzoBYad7QXhl780NIh7h_MAp0aLcQNSAHtCG6CdZywoNst5bEc-rtd2MY2aL3zddrh_zPxQ-6TE05rqWQQ8fasbTj808khgybywwj4GC5AA4vaPSksEsqeuk414hmBizZUNlLEL0W4k1LzovlFuLFZwQrVBCTh1J_gKEQ0rpCMjag7gY)

Comment: If you only store the token in local storage, then you'll need to somehow send it with the request (header, cookie, query parameter, whatever). If you already send it with a request... well, we won't be guessing how you do it ;)

Comment: Thank you Jakub. But I need to send token from backend to frontend (I know it's strange). So how i can read jwt token for auto-logged user?

Comment: Why is it strange? I mean, isn't the server who creates the token and passes it to the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found it:
$this->get('lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_manager')->create($this->getUser());